# loop of Pool.map and memory errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am experiencing a memory issue when I'm trying to run the below problem.

Consider a function that for each argument, arg_i_j, it returns a pandas dataframe as,

```
def some_fun(arg_i_j):
   ...
   return DF_i_j
```

Now, I have structured all arguments that I want to test in the following format,

```
All_lists = [ [arg_0_0,..., arg_0_N], ..., [arg_k_0,..., arg_k_N]],
```

and I'm trying to execute the following code in the main function

```
# Version A
results_per_list = []
the_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count(), initializer=...,initargs=...)
for a_list in All_lists:
   results = the_pool.map(some_fun, a_list) 
   results_per_list.append(results)
the_pool.close()
the_pool.join()

# then use results_per_list to do operations
```

and I end up with the error,

```
...\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
MemoryError
```

1) Anyone has any idea how can I resolve that issue??

2) Do you see any problem in creating a "pool" object for each "a_list" in "All_lists" like below?

```
# Version B
results_per_list = []
for a_list in All_lists:
   the_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count(), initializer=...,initargs=...)
   results = the_pool.map(some_fun, a_list) 
   results_per_list.append(results)
   the_pool.close()
   the_pool.join()
```

Comment: The first thing to try is to add `if __name__ == "__main__":` before your main piece of code.

Comment: This has been done - here I post the idea of the problem.